# Is there any negative to calling a method after a router push? (Vue.js)

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Is there any negative to calling a method after a router push?

eg.

```
if (response.data.processPayment.successfulPayment) {
   this.$router.push('/success-payment')
   this.gtm_tracking(response.data.processPayment)
} else {
   ...
}
```

As opposed to having the `gtm_tracking` before the `$router.push` incase something fails in the tracking I dont want it to prevent the redirect.
It appears to work fine. I’m just wondering if anyone knows any gotchas with doing this?

Comment: I can't find any documentation for you, so I'm not answering, but pushing a path to this.$router doesn't stop the current function from executing, as you've discovered.

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't find any documentation either. I'll leave it like this and update if I find any issues in future.

Comment: There shouldn't be any problems, as long as the method you call doesn't interfere with router directly or indirectly (does redirects itself, reads location, etc).

Answer (score 2):

To prevent the tracking code from disrupting the route push,you can catch the exception of the code:

```js
if (response.data.processPayment.successfulPayment) {

   // try to execute the tracking code
   try{
      this.gtm_tracking(response.data.processPayment);
   }catch(e){
      // handle tracking error
   }

   // this will allways be executed :)
   this.$router.push('/success-payment')

} else {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, yeah thats a good option. I was more wondering if the way I have done it has any negatives as its a bit cleaner than the try, catch. And I would want it to throw the error if there is one, rather than suppress it, so that I can pick it up in the error tracking logs.

Comment: @DavidNorth Actually in most web-event-tracking cases,the tracking api **should designed to be asynchronous**，for example:push a tracking task into a pending queue. So the call of 'gtm_tracking' should not cause any error  :)